# How to fetch the result from multiple tables to gridview?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

**Question:**
  Let's Say i have two tables,

```
Table1            Table2
-authorId         -username
-moderatorId      -id
```

As of now my view looks like this,

```
[    
              'label' => 'Author', 
              'value' => function($something){
                    return $something->transaction->authorId ?? null; 
              },
              'attribute' => 'author'
],
```

**Expected Result**
  I would like to display author name of every post in gridview,
I tried using authorId but it displays only id of the author.
How should i use the "authorId" column to map to "username" column.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Maybe relations is what you are looking for http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: If you have foreign keys in database in said tables, you can easily generate relations in models via gii and then simply use them in views (see link above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you Table1 related  Model  add two Active Relation (one for Author and One Moderator ) for retrive the related  names

Setup Table1 model

```
/* ActiveRelation  for Author*/
    public function getAuthor()
{
        return $this->hasOne(Table2Model::className(), ['id' => 'author_id']);
    }

/* ActiveRelation  for Moderator */
    public function getModerator ()
{
        return $this->hasOne(Table2Model::className(), ['id' => 'moderator_id']);
    }
```

then build two getter one for Author name and one for Moderator name

```
/* Getter for author name */
public function getAuthorName() {
        return $this->author->username;
}

/* Getter for moderator name */
public function getModeratorName() {
        return $this->moderator->username;
}
```

add your model attribute labels

```
    /* Your model attribute labels */
public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            /* Your other attribute labels */
            'AuthorName' => Yii::t('app', 'Author Name'),
            'ModeratorName' => Yii::t('app', 'Moderator Name')
        ];
}
```

then your gridView  you can user the new getters

```
'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ....
        ....
        'authorName',
        'moderatorName',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
```

Comment: It Worked thanks mate :)
How can i proceed with an search box at the gridview for this ?Any ideas?

Comment: Hi again,it would be great if you could help me with the issue i am facing now, the added updates works fine in one gridview page.But there is also an another gridview page which extends this first model, I get the "Getting unknown property: app\models\Transactions::authorName"

Comment: You should post a new question .. clearly described with related code ..